# How do I get a lower/higher voltage from a cuk converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, converter

By definition, "The Ćuk converter is a type of DC/DC converter that has an output voltage magnitude that is either greater than or less than the input voltage magnitude"

So I was wondering how I can get:
a) An output voltage lower than input voltage
b) An output voltage higher than input voltage

Also, for a Cuk converter, is it possible to easily switch between low and high output voltage configurations, without changing the entire circuit?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=cuk

Comment: Im sorry, but I found nothing in the link you provided that answers my question..

Comment: The duty cycle (and input polarity) of your input can really determine how you can get a higher or lower output... That's really the whole point of of Cuk converter. The main difference between a standard buck-boost and a Cuk converter is that a buck-boost transfers the energy on the inductor whereas the Cuk transfers the energy on the capacitor.

Comment: Oh okay. But wouldn't I be able to get a lower voltage/ higher voltage output for a buck and a boost converter- again just by varying the duty cycle? How is this different different from varying the duty cycle for a Cuk converter?

Comment: Now, I need to point you to a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%86uk_converter) about this. There are formulas for fundamental design.

Comment: @noorav I see you didn't bother to read any of my links You have to understand how they work 1st.   https://www.powerelectronics.com/power-management/step-down-dc-dc-converter-eliminates-ferrite-cores-50khz-enabling-power-supply-chip and to your second question. No. YOu use a Buck Boost config.